# optional, but unique SlugField

Tags: django, django-models

I need a `SlugField` which is optional and if not empty it should be unique.

If I take the `SlugField` of django, the empty string is allowed and there will be an empty string in the database. But if it is unique, only one row with the empty string is allowed.

My `SlugField` should be unique if it is set, or `None` (`NULL`) if it is not set.

At database level it works: The unique constraint ignores `NULL` values.

Since I don't want to modify too many places, a database field would be the best solution.

Comment: you could sanitize your data, and ensure that empty strings are converted/saved as `None`

Comment: Did you try using [`null=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null)?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I am not at work now, I don't have the source here. But AFAIK I use `SlugField(null=True, unique=True, blank=True)`

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Yes, the code is: SlugField(null=True, unique=True, blank=True).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
from django.db.models import SlugField

# Inspired by: https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py

class SlugOrNullField(SlugField):
    """
    Don't insert empty slugs. If the slug is empty, insert NULL.

    Usecase: Unique, but optional slug. Unique constrains only applies
             to the values which are not NULL.
    """
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        slug = SlugField(null=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    """
    If you want to be really sure, that no empty slug is in your table, you can use this
    in a schema migration (south):
    """
    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.execute("ALTER TABLE myapp_foomodel add CONSTRAINT slug_not_empty CHECK (slug<>'')")
    """
    If you have a empty slug in your table, you can use this in a data migration:
    """
    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.execute("UPDATE myapp_foomodel SET slug=NULL WHERE slug='' ")



    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value=value.strip()
        if not value:
            return None
        return value

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "SlugField"

#South Plugin registrieren
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
add_introspection_rules([], ["^djangotools\.dbfields\.SlugOrNullField"])
```